# What is the default "cursive" font for macOS?

Tags: font, font-book

I am working on a Processing project for fun and I wanted to use the cursive font that is usually called in HTML and everything else, "cursive" or "Cursive," but in Processing it does the default sans-serif (Arial I think). Does anyone know what the actual name of this font is? "Times" and "Marker Felt" do work, but "monospace" also doesn't.

A snippet of my code (though not necessary as this is a question about macs and not code):

`textFont(createFont("Cursive", width*0.75/9));`

Post-scriptum: I did check font book and wikipedia, but not thoroughly.

Comment: Actually, I just checked Pages.app and it seems like it is Apple Chancery. Still this question is open to answers about monospace and other default fonts, where to find them, and stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebPreferences has properties for each of the standard font families. See

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webpreferences/1536642-standardfontfamily

Apple doesn't publish the defaults for each of these, but you can use an Xcode playground to quickly print them:

```
let prefs = WebPreferences()
prefs.standardFontFamily  // Times
prefs.sansSerifFontFamily // Helvetica
prefs.serifFontFamily     // Times
prefs.fixedFontFamily     // Courier
prefs.fantasyFontFamily   // Papyrus
prefs.cursiveFontFamily   // Apple Chancery
```

[image]

Comment: Neat thanks! The playground code isn't working for me macOSSierra 10.13.3 Xcode 9.2 it said I couldn't import Cocoa "no such module 'Coco'" so something is definitely wrong lol. Maybe I started the wrong playground type. I haven't used Playgrounds much. I'll try again.

Comment: @cmarangu Don’t forget to pick macOS playground when creating it, not iOS, perhaps that’s the issue?

Comment: yup just figured that out and it works!